# Putting different custom colors in different facets in multiple density plots using geom_density()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a faceted density plot using geom_density using a data a part of which is shown below

```
  x     |   cl   |   |type   | ccl
 0.919 |Group 8 |Candidate |#BCBDDC
 0.538 |Group 4 |Candidate |#FDAE6B
 0.715 |Group 3 |Candidate |#A1D99B
 0.849 |Group 2 |Candidate |#FC9272
 0.710 |Group 2 |Candidate |#FC9272
 0.836 |Group 2 |Candidate |#FC9272
```

Here each observation belongs to one of 8 groups (given by "cl") and each x is either of type "candidate" or type "Non-candidate" (given by "type"). The column "ccl" gives the color preference for a particular x. I want to do a faceted density plot where the facets will be given by the groups and each facet will have 2 density plots, one for "candidate" and the other for "Non-candidate". To do it I use the following code

```
jcl <- dd_f_c$ccl
names(jcl) <- dd_f_c$type

p <- ggplot(data = dd_f_c, aes(x=x)) + geom_density(aes(x = x), alpha = 0.4)+ facet_wrap( ~ cl, ncol = 4) +aes(fill = type)+ scale_fill_manual(values = jcl) + ylim(0, 11) + theme_bw()
p <- p  + theme(strip.background = element_rect(fill = alpha('black', 0.1)))
p +labs(x="Classification probability",y="Density")+theme(legend.title = element_blank(), legend.position ="bottom")
```

Here dd_f_c denotes the dataframe containing the data shown above.

Using the above code I get the following figure

[image: Density plot]

I want different colors for the different facets, I want to indicate the candidates using a dark custom color and the non candidate by a light custom color (the preferred colors being given in ccl). For example I want the density plot of candidates in group 1 to be light red and the non candidates to be dark red, the density plot candidates in group 2 to be light green and the non candidates in group 2 dark green etc.

```
structure(list(x = c(0.919, 0.538, 0.715, 0.849, 0.71, 0.836, 
0.992, 0.644, 0.997, 0.99, 0.961, 0.662, 0.551, 0.966, 0.384, 
0.998, 0.672, 0.946, 0.754, 0.995, 0.404, 0.716, 0.833, 0.438, 
0.953, 0.843, 0.988, 0.954, 0.834, 0.959, 0.766, 0.99, 0.967, 
0.985, 0.662, 0.779, 0.992, 0.989, 0.838, 0.739, 0.984, 0.994
), cl = structure(c(8L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Group 1", 
"Group 2", "Group 3", "Group 4", "Group 5", "Group 6", "Group 7", 
"Group 8"), class = "factor"), type = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Candidate", "Non-Candidate"
), class = "factor"), ccl = structure(c(8L, 13L, 7L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 10L, 13L, 7L, 13L, 12L, 12L, 7L, 11L, 11L, 7L, 10L, 10L, 
12L, 10L, 11L, 10L, 12L, 10L, 12L, 12L, 10L, 12L, 10L, 12L, 7L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 10L, 12L, 12L, 10L), .Label = c("#00441B", 
"#08306B", "#525252", "#67000D", "#7F2704", "#8C510A", "#A1D99B", 
"#BCBDDC", "#C51B7D", "#DCDCDC", "#F7CBE4", "#FC9272", "#FDAE6B"
), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(636L, 
637L, 638L, 639L, 640L, 641L, 642L, 643L, 644L, 645L, 835L, 836L, 
837L, 838L, 839L, 840L, 841L, 842L, 843L, 844L, 845L, 846L, 847L, 
848L, 849L, 850L, 851L, 852L, 853L, 854L, 855L, 1635L, 1636L, 
1637L, 1638L, 1639L, 1640L, 1641L, 1642L, 1643L, 1644L, 1645L
))
```

Any help with this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: It's a little bit difficult to recreate and test this without a sample data set. What happens if you just move `fill = ccl` into the `aes(` statement of `geom_density`? Like this: `ggplot(data = dd_f_c, aes(x=x)) + 
      geom_density(aes(x = x, fill = ccl), alpha = 0.4) + 
      facet_wrap( ~ cl, ncol = 4) +
      theme_bw()`

Comment: Hi! Thank You for your reply, if I do as you suggested then I get different colors but the colors are getting jumbled up, i.e. the right color does not get assigned to the right facet.

Comment: Can you post an example data set? You could subset your data, and post it using `dput(data)`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I have posted a small subset of my data using dput in the original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO, there are three possibilities:

1. Specify the colour for each combination of `cl` and `type` explicitely (as attempted by the OP)
2. Use the built-in mechanisms for the `fill` and `alpha` aesthetics
3. Use a paired colour palette with the `interaction()` of `cl` and `type`

This answer focuses on variants 2 and 3:

#### Variant 2

```
# make up sample data
n_rows <- 100L
set.seed(1L)
DF <- data.frame(x = runif(n_rows),
                 cl = sample(paste("Group", 1:4), n_rows, TRUE),
                 type = sample(paste0(c("", "Non-"), "Candidate"), n_rows, TRUE))

# create plot
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(DF) + 
  aes(x = x, fill = cl, alpha = type, linetype = type) + 
  geom_density() + 
  scale_alpha_manual(values = c("Candidate" = 0.2, "Non-Candidate" = 0.4)) + 
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c("Candidate" = "dashed", "Non-Candidate" = "solid")) + 
  facet_wrap(~ cl, ncol = 2) +
  labs(x = "Classification probability", y = "Density") + 
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(strip.background = element_rect(fill = alpha('black', 0.1))) + 
  theme(legend.title = element_blank(), legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

#### Variant 3

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(DF) + 
  aes(x = x, fill = interaction(type, cl)) + 
  geom_density(alpha = 0.4) + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Paired") +
  facet_wrap(~ cl, ncol = 2) +
  labs(x = "Classification probability", y = "Density") + 
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(strip.background = element_rect(fill = alpha('black', 0.1))) + 
  theme(legend.title = element_blank(), legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

The selected ColorBrewer palette consists of a pair-wise sequence of light and dark colours which map to `Candidate` and `Non-Candidate` as requested by the OP.

`RColorBrewer::display.brewer.pal(8, "Paired")` can be used to display the palette. Unfortunately, this palette is limited to 12 colours (6 pairs) while the OP needs 16 colours (8 pairs) for the 8 groups.

The `unikn` package includes a palette with 16 colours (8 pairs). Using this, the code becomes:

```
# make up sample data for 8 groups
n_rows <- 100L
set.seed(1L)
DF <- data.frame(x = runif(n_rows),
                 cl = sample(paste("Group", 1:8), n_rows, TRUE),
                 type = sample(paste0(c("", "Non-"), "Candidate"), n_rows, TRUE))
# create plot
library(ggplot2)
library(unikn)
ggplot(DF) + 
  aes(x = x, fill = interaction(type, cl)) + 
  geom_density(alpha = 0.4) + 
  scale_fill_manual(
    values  = usecol(pal_unikn_pair, 16L)[1:16 + c(+1L, -1L)]) +
  facet_wrap(~ cl, ncol = 4) +
  labs(x = "Classification probability", y = "Density") + 
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(strip.background = element_rect(fill = alpha('black', 0.1))) + 
  theme(legend.title = element_blank(), legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

`usecol(pal_unikn_pair, 16L)[1:16 + c(+1L, -1L)]` switches the order of colours pairwise because the colours are ordered dark and light while we need light and dark. Use `seecol(pal_unikn_pair)` to show the palette.

Comment: Isn't this the better answer? The display is certainly cleaner and has better legends.

Answer (score 0):

Using a slightly modified version of the provided data set:

```
> dput(dd_f_c)
structure(list(X = c(642L, 841L, 842L, 844L, 846L, 848L, 851L, 
853L, 1642L, 1645L, 639L, 640L, 641L, 835L, 836L, 843L, 847L, 
849L, 850L, 852L, 854L, 1638L, 1639L, 1643L, 1644L, 638L, 644L, 
837L, 840L, 855L, 637L, 643L, 645L, 1635L, 1636L, 1637L, 1640L, 
1641L), x = c(0.992, 0.672, 0.946, 0.995, 0.716, 0.438, 0.988, 
0.834, 0.838, 0.994, 0.849, 0.71, 0.836, 0.961, 0.662, 0.754, 
0.833, 0.953, 0.843, 0.954, 0.959, 0.662, 0.779, 0.739, 0.984, 
0.715, 0.997, 0.551, 0.998, 0.766, 0.538, 0.644, 0.99, 0.99, 
0.967, 0.985, 0.992, 0.989), cl = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L), .Label = c("Group 1", "Group 2", "Group 3", "Group 4"
), class = "factor"), type = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), .Label = c("Candidate", "Non-Candidate"), class = "factor"), 
    ccl = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("#A1D99B", 
    "#BCBDDC", "#DCDCDC", "#F7CBE4", "#FC9272", "#FDAE6B"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-38L))
```

The following code assigns the two types within facets the associated colour:

```
ggplot(data = dd_f_c, aes(x=x)) + geom_density(aes(x = x, fill = ccl), alpha = 0.4) + facet_wrap( ~ cl, ncol = 4) + theme_bw()
```

[image]

The legend doesn't make much sense now, of course, and all facets would need individual legends to distinguish `Candidate` and `Non-Candidate`. The easiest way to do this is actually to create separate plots and combining them with `gridExtra`:

```
library(gridExtra)
xs <- split(dd_f_c,f = dd_f_c$cl)
p1 <- ggplot(xs$`Group 1`, aes(x=x)) + 
      geom_density(aes(x = x, fill = type), alpha = 0.4) +
      scale_fill_manual(values = unique(dd_f_c$ccl[dd_f_c$cl == "Group 1"])) +
      facet_wrap(~cl, ncol=1)
p2 <- ggplot(xs$`Group 2`, aes(x=x)) + 
      geom_density(aes(x = x, fill = type), alpha = 0.4) +
      scale_fill_manual(values = unique(dd_f_c$ccl[dd_f_c$cl == "Group 2"])) +
      facet_wrap(~cl, ncol=1)
p3 <- ggplot(xs$`Group 3`, aes(x=x)) + 
      geom_density(aes(x = x, fill = type), alpha = 0.4) +
      scale_fill_manual(values = unique(dd_f_c$ccl[dd_f_c$cl == "Group 3"])) +
      facet_wrap(~cl, ncol=1)
p4 <- ggplot(xs$`Group 4`, aes(x=x)) + 
      geom_density(aes(x = x, fill = type), alpha = 0.4) +
      scale_fill_manual(values = unique(dd_f_c$ccl[dd_f_c$cl == "Group 4"])) +
      facet_wrap(~cl, ncol=1)

grid.arrange(p1,p2,p3,p4)
```

[image]